# Error using IRMI imputation

Tags: r, vim

I've been trying to use irmi from VIM package to replace NA's.
My data looks something like this:

```
> str(sub_mex)
'data.frame':   21 obs. of  83 variables:
 $ pH                       : num  7.2 7.4 7.4 7.36 7.2 7.82 7.67 7.73 7.79 7.7 ...
 $ Cond                     : num  1152 1078 1076 1076 1018 ...
 $ CO3                      : num  NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Mg                       : num  25.8 24.9 24.3 24.8 23.4 ...
 $ NO3                      : num  49.7 25.6 27.1 39.6 52.8 ...
 $ Cd                       : num  0.0088 0.0104 0.0085 0.0092 0.0086 ...
 $ As_H                     : num  0.006 0.0059 0.0056 0.0068 0.0073 ...
 $ As_F                     : num  0.0056 0.0058 0.0057 0.0066 0.0065 0.004 0.004 0.004 0.0048 0.0078 ...
 $ As_FC                    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 0.0028 ...
 $ Pb                       : num  0.0097 0.0096 0.0092 0.01 0.0093 0.0275 0.024 0.0255 0.031 0.024 ...
 $ Fe                       : num  0.39 0.26 0.27 0.28 0.32 0.135 0.08 NA 0.13 NA ...
 $ No_EPT                   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I've subset my `sub_mex` dataset to analyze observations separately, so i have `sub_t` dataset. Which look something like this

```
  > str(sub_t)
    'data.frame':   5 obs. of  83 variables:
     $ pH                       : num  7.82 7.67 7.73 7.79 7.7
     $ CO3                      : num  45 NA 37.2 41.9 40.3
     $ Mg                       : num  41.3 51.4 47.7 51.8 53
     $ NO3                      : num  47.1 40.7 39.9 42.1 37.6
     $ Cd                       : num  0.0173 0.0145 0.016 0.016 0.0154
     $ As_H                     : num  0.00949 0.01009 0.00907 0.00972 0.00954
     $ As_F                     : num  0.004 0.004 0.004 0.0048 0.0078
     $ As_FC                    : num  NA NA NA NA 0.0028
     $ Pb                       : num  0.0275 0.024 0.0255 0.031 0.024
     $ Fe                       : num  0.135 0.08 NA 0.13 NA
     $ No_EPT                   : int  0 0 0 0 0
```

I impute NA's  of the `sub_mex` dataset using:

`imp_mexi <- irmi(sub_mex)` which works fine

However when I try to impute the subset `sub_t` I got the following error message:

```
 > imp_t <- irmi(sub_t) 
    Error in indexNA2s[, variable[j]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this? I want to impute my data `sub_t` and I don't want to use a subset of the `ìmp_mexi` imputed dataset.
Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and discovered that one of the columns in my dataframe was entirely missing- hence the out of bounds error.